# Polkadot/Substrate estimate tx fee from Rust

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, rust

In the polkadot js/ts library there is a method to estimate tx fee:

```
const info = await api.tx.balances
  .transfer(recipient, 123)
  .paymentInfo(sender);
```

We want to do the same (estimate tx fee) using the Rust substrate_api_client library. But the method (paymentInfo) seems not to be implemented in this client. Anyone know how to do this (estimate tx fee) from rust?

Thanks very much
Regards;
Fernando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What PolkadotJS is doing under the hood is a query the node via the [RPC call payment_queryInfo](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#queryinfoextrinsic-bytes-at-blockhash-runtimedispatchinfo) to retrieve the fee information for an encoded extrinsic.

An example using CURL to request this information for a extrinsic of my local node:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "payment_queryInfo", "params":["0x4d028400d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d018890cd70c7ae36911d36c9a740083788213fb4c815ae570e1ef0a6060987cb159b16d4a20e4404061e9b47689e7a86e2c2b651b3634697021f0190ea80066f8e550200000500008eaf04151687736326c9fea17e25fc5287613693c912909cb226aa4794f26a4813000064a7b3b6e00d"]}' localhost:9933
```

With the response you are looking for:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"weight":{"ref_time":166860000,"proof_size":0},"class":"normal","partialFee":"253158149"},"id":1}
```

You can do the same in RUST using the [**jsonrpsee**](https://github.com/paritytech/jsonrpc) a Rust implementation of JSON-RPC 2.0 Specification.